# Whats the vulkan equialent for D3D12 ClearUnorderedAccessView

Tags: c++, vulkan, direct3d, directx-12

I need to clear an unordered access view. In D3D12 you have ClearUnorderedAccessView(Uint/Float).

How can I achieve this using Vulkan?

Comment: What is an "unordered access view", and what does that function do?

Comment: @NicolBolas https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12graphicscommandlist-clearunorderedaccessviewuint

Comment: a quick google turned up https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb/issues/28 so I'm guessing `vkCmdFillBuffer` is what you need

Comment: I found that but thats not the same. In case  the buffer is 10MB you need to provide a sys mem buffer of 10MB. ClearUnorderedAccessView works like ClearRenderTargetView

Comment: nope, definitely only takes 4 bytes of input https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCmdFillBuffer.html

Comment: you are right , sadly there is no other way ...

Comment: @MarkaRagnos0815: What is "sadly" about that? The function doesn't take a buffer the size of the destination storage.

Comment: D3D11/D3D12 versions takes 4 components to be able to clear RGBA buffers using different values and it supports "rects" to just clear part of a buffer. this is usefull in case you have a twio dimensional image

Comment: @MarkaRagnos0815: As does `vkCmdClearColorImage`. `vkCmdFillBuffer` is for *buffers*, not images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "unordered access view" in D3D is, in Vulkan, is usually a storage image.

Vulkan has no facilities to allow you to directly manipulate the contents of a resource through a descriptor index/reference. Only shader processes can modify the contents of a descriptor through a descriptor index. To modify a resource via a CPU command, you must actually access that resource.

To clear an image means using `vkCmdClearColor/DepthStencilImage`. This function can only be called outside of a render pass. While functions exist to clear attached images, you cannot clear non-attachment images inside of a render pass.

If this was a unordered access view of a buffer, you would use `vkCmdFillBuffer` instead.